# rbenv is not seeing a Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to set the environment for a RoR project on a new work pc.

When I try to install using `bundle install`, I get the following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.5
```

I'm using rbenv so I tried all the necessary rbenv tricks. Specifically I tried the following commands, each seperately:

```
rbenv install 2.5.5
rbenv rehash
rbenv local 2.5.5
rbenv global 2.5.5
```

I then retry `bundle install` but I'm still getting the same error.

I even tried

```
rbenv uninstall 2.6.8
```

but I'm getting:

```
rbenv: version `2.6.8' not installed
```

I of course tried restarting the computer totally after each of the steps but I'm still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the correct version?

Comment: what do you get with `which ruby`? It looks like 2.6.8 is installed outside of rbenv

Comment: which ruby gives: /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: Why don't you just change the `.ruby-version` and `Gemfile`? It should not complain anymore.

Comment: I need it to be 2.5.5
And it is both 2.5.5 in the .ruby-version file and the Gemfile

Comment: @mrateb -Yup, this is system installed ruby, you need to remove it. What system are you on?

Comment: @BroiSatse this is a mac monterey. Does this answer the question?

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove the system installed ruby, you just need rbenv to be first in your `$PATH` order. `which ruby` should point to `~/.rbenv/shims/ruby`. The fact that it is pointing to `/usr/bin/ruby` means that rbenv is not setup correctly, or you need to reload your terminal so that bash/zsh is using the updated $PATH variable. Take a look at the install instructions here and maybe try the rbenv doctor script that should help debug what is going wrong https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation